# How to add more images in multiple input tag html?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-templates

Suppose I have a input tag like this

```
<input type="file" name="Posts" id="FilesForUpload" multiple>
```

When I Click on this it takes a file (or multiple files) for Example i chose - A.jpg , B.jpg
Now after I selected these two images now I want to add a third Image say C.jpg. So when I click on the input tag again then it replaces A.jpg and B.jpg. I know its obvious that it will replace those two, But is there any way so that it does not replace previous files.

I am using Django Framework to build my Project and I am stuck on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot prevent them from being overwritten, but you can cache files as they are uploaded, so that they are saved when the user adds new ones.

Comment: Any Idea on how to do that??

Comment: Add an event listener for the upload using JavaScript.